# Add custom column with metadata on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm want to add custom column(s) with some meta data on the WooCommerce admin orders list. I found, and modified this for my needs, and put it in my functions.php:

```php
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] );
    
    //edit this for your column(s)
    //all of your columns will be added before the actions column
    $new_columns['dname'] = 'Dogs Name';
    $new_columns['additional_allergies'] = 'Allergies';
    
    //stop editing
    $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] = $columns[ 'order_actions' ];
    return $new_columns;
}
```

At checkout I collect these two meta keys:

- dname
- additional_allergies

However, my current code only shows empty columns, any advice to add the meta datea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column` hook can be used to add a header.

```php
// Add a Header
function custom_shop_order_column( $columns ) {
    // Add new columns
    $columns['dogs_name'] = __( 'Dogs Name', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['additional_allergies'] = __( 'Allergies', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 10, 1 );
```

---

The `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column` hook will be needed to populate the column.

- **Note:** it is important to determine whether it is metadata that belongs to the `$order` object or whether it is metadata that belongs to the order `$items` and based on that you will have to use 1 of the 2 answers below.

**1a:** In case the metadata belongs to the `$order` object, you can use:

```php
//  Populate the Column
function custom_shop_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Get order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Compare column name
        if ( $column == 'dogs_name' ) {
            // Get meta, use the correct meta key!
            $dogs_name = $order->get_meta( 'dname' );
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty( $dogs_name ) ) {
                // Output
                echo $dogs_name;
            } else {
                // Output
                echo __( 'Meta key is wrong or not found for this order', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }

        // Compare column name
        if ( $column == 'additional_allergies' ) {
            // Get meta, use the correct meta key!
            $allergies = $order->get_meta( 'additional_allergies' );
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty( $allergies ) ) {
                // Output
                echo $allergies;
            } else {
                // Output
                echo __( 'Meta key is wrong or not found for this order', 'woocommerce' );
            }       
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_shop_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
```

**1b:** However, when the metadata belong to the order `$items` then an adjustment will be necessary in the above answer, since an `$order` can consist of several `$items`, we will loop through the `$order` object with [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```php
//  Populate the Column
function custom_shop_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Get order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Initialize
        $dogs_name_arr = array();
        $allergies_arr = array();
        
        // Loop trough order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
            // Get meta, use the correct meta key!
            $dogs_name = $item->get_meta( 'dname' );
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $dogs_name ) ) {
                // Push to array
                $dogs_name_arr[] = $dogs_name;
            }
            
            // Get meta, use the correct meta key!
            $allergies = $item->get_meta( 'additional_allergies' );
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $allergies ) ) {
                // Push to array
                $allergies_arr[] = $allergies;
            }
        }
        
        // Compare column name
        if ( $column == 'dogs_name' ) {
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $dogs_name_arr ) ) {
                // Output
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $dogs_name_arr ) . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                // Output
                echo __( 'Meta key is wrong or not found for the order items', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }

        // Compare column name
        if ( $column == 'additional_allergies' ) {
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $allergies_arr ) ) {
                // Output
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $allergies_arr ) . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                // Output
                echo __( 'Meta key is wrong or not found for the order items', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_shop_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
```